MapBox Directions API returns wrong response
I'm using MapBox Directions API. It doesn't work corrent with some locations.
For example
https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/driving-traffic/54.7124996,25.2623823;54.6813069,25.3061969?access_token={ACESS_TOKEN}
returns me response where distance and duration equals 0 and that is wrong.
{"routes":[{"weight_typical":0,"duration_typical":0,"weight_name":"auto","weight":0,"duration":0,"distance":0,"legs":[{"via_waypoints":[],"admins":[{"iso_3166_1":""}],"weight_typical":0,"duration_typical":0,"weight":0,"duration":0,"steps":[],"distance":0,"summary":""}],"geometry":"yanyCiyslI??"}],"waypoints":[{"distance":7001.088,"name":"","location":[54.665333,25.308605]},{"distance":1629.751,"name":"","location":[54.665333,25.308605]}],"code":"Ok","uuid":"G3kVpZdvWK7iq2gf8GyPxMe3vAZ5Ppxb_lBuh8LIa0bAwfCihcblDg=="}

If we request the same coordinates in GoogleMaps API we have such directions and distance
I tried to use POST request and swapping the coordinates. This didn't help.

You are sending the coordinates in the wrong order.
In Mapbox you've to specify waypoints in this order: longitude, latitude.
